# How to know which row tapped or selected in ListView Xamarin Form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin. I have a question about ListView in Xamarin form.
How do I know which row or index everytime I tab (or select) in the listView? Below is the code I tried, but e.SelectedItem does not show anything. Thanks for helping.

```
listView.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) => {

    if (e.SelectedItem == null) return; // don't do anything if we just de-selected the row

    await DisplayAlert("Tapped", e.SelectedItem + " row was selected", "OK");

    ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null; // de-select the row
};
```

Comment: e.SelectedItem should return the row data. What are you using in the ItemSource ?

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution. I am iOS developer before, trying to programme with Xamarin form. In iOS, i can get the index of the row so I can get the data from that. But in Xamarin Form it return the row data itself. Very convinient.

Comment: May be you can add the solution you found in the answer section. That will help someone in future

Answer (score 6):

I have a list view and on click I have to go to the details view page. The following is the code that I use for the same.

```
listView.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.SelectedItem == null)
                {
                    // don't do anything if we just de-selected the row
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    Resource resource = e.SelectedItem as Resource;
                    listView.SelectedItem = null;
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new ResourceDetails(resource));
                }
            };
```

In your case I would modify the code as follows :

```
listView.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) => {

    if (e.SelectedItem == null) return; // don't do anything if we just de-selected the row

    await DisplayAlert("Tapped", (e.SelectedItem as YourDataType).Name + " row was selected", "OK");

    ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null; // de-select the row
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution how to find the index of the row. :)

```
listView.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) => {
                if (e.SelectedItem == null) return; // don't do anything if we just de-selected the row
                Person person = (Person)e.SelectedItem;
                int index = -1;

                for(int i = 0; i < people.Count; i++)
                {
                    if(people[i] == person)
                    {
                        index = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                await DisplayAlert("Tapped", person.Name + " row was selected " + index.ToString(), "OK");

                ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null; // de-select the row
            };
```

Comment: Might not be correct if the list contains duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler and quicker solution for this would be to use IndexOf on the ItemSource - in your case "people"

```
int index = people.IndexOf(person);
```

this would remove your for loop

Comment: Will not work correctly if the list contains duplicates.